# How to author custom objects in a tile map?

Tags: tiled, editors, map-editor, asset-workflow

I've been using Tiled for my game engine but for objects I have to use points on an object layer and give it a name and use that to create map items in-game. This is really inefficient as I don't want to have to copy paste every time I want to place down a ammo pack.

Is there a better workflow I can use to create custom objects and instantiate them?

Ideally I'd like to export to XML, but that's not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1):

so as it turns out Tiled already lets you give tiles properties, just click the '+' in the tileset editor and you can add variables which can be accessed by a library such as tmxlite, this took me about 5 minutes to implement in my engine [image]
[image]
[image]

[image]